# How to make use of pre-trained word embeddings when training a model in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

With things like neural networks (NNs) in keras it is very clear how to use word embeddings within the training of the NN, you can simply do something like

```
embeddings = ...
model = Sequential(Embedding(...),
                   layer1,
                   layer2,...)
```

But I'm unsure of how to do this with algorithms in sklearn such as SVMs, NBs, and logistic regression. I understand that there is a `Pipeline` method, which works simply (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) like

```
pip = Pipeline([(Countvectorizer()), (TfidfTransformer()), (Classifier())])
pip.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But how can I include loaded word embeddings in this pipeline? Or should it somehow be included outside the pipeline? I can't find much documentation online about how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FunctionTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) class.
If your goal is to have a transformer that takes a matrix of indexes and outputs a 3d tensor with word vectors, then this should suffice:

```
# this assumes you're using numpy ndarrays
word_vecs_matrix = get_wv_matrix()  # pseudo-code
def transform(x):
    return word_vecs_matrix[x]
transformer = FunctionTransformer(transform)
```

Be aware that, unlike keras, the word vector **will not** be fine tuned using some kind of gradient descent

Comment: And this FunctionTransformer() can be passed into the Pipeline?

Comment: Yes, it can. It's pretty much its whole purpose

Answer (score 2):

There is any easy way to get word embeddings transformers with the [Zeugma](https://github.com/nkthiebaut/zeugma) package.

It handles the downloading of the pre-trained embeddings and returns a "Transformer interface" for the embeddings.

For example if you want to use the averge of the GloVe embeddings for sentences representations you'd just have to write:

```
    from zeugma.embeddings import EmbeddingTransformer
    glove = EmbeddingTransformer('glove')
```

Here `glove` is a sklearn transformer has the standard transform method that takes a list of sentences as input and outputs a design matrix, just like Tfidftransformer. You can get the resulting embeddings with `embeddings = glove.transform(['first sentence of the corpus', 'another sentence'])` and `embeddings` woud contain a 2 x N matrics, where N is the dimension of the chosen embedding. Note that you don't have to bother with embeddings downloading, or local loading if you've already done it, Zeugma handles this transparently.

Hope this helps